# CSS transition is not working with Show-More

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js app which has a card component that has read more link. when the user clicks on read more link the card should expand, I have used "react-show-more" https://github.com/One-com/react-show-more. I need to add smooth expand to the card when press the read more link with CSS Transition rule but the CSS transition is not working. This is my card component. and you can find live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-http-cfz7p?fontsize=14

```
 return (
    <CardOuter>
      <CardIcon>
        <img className="CardIcons" alt="cardIcon" src={Icon} />
      </CardIcon>
      <CardContent>
        <h3>{Title}</h3>
        <ShowMore
          lines={5}
          more={<Link className="link-right" Content="Read More" />}
          less={<Link className="link-right-sl" Content="Show less" />}
          anchorClass="showMore"
        >
          {Description}
        </ShowMore>
      </CardContent>
    </CardOuter>
  );
```

Comment: I'm the one who opened that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found another npm that has smooth expand,

```
https://github.com/tinacious/react-animated-show-more
```